# how do you test a user created directory name so it does not include illegal charactors in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, mkdir

we have our code set up to create a directory based on the desired directory name so the user would through html choose a directory name and it would be created based on their name, the obvious problem comes when they enter characters like ?)(#$^&^%$#@/|][{}<>,. or unicode characters as certain characters are not allowed to be within a url.

how would we test the string to replace any illegal characters with _ or ''?

here is the code so far

```
//Removes illegal characters
$game_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]/','',$game_name);
//grab current directory name
$currentdirname = dirname(__file__);

//create new directory that uses game_name and current_directory
$game_directory = $currentdirname . '/' . $game_name;

//creates directory
mkdir($game_directory, 0700);
```

Comment: Why do you want user created directories?  Can you just have a row per entry and do database-driven routing?

Comment: Why are you letting your users name your directories? Why do you care what they name the directories?

Comment: we are having the user create the directories so it is named after their profile so they can easily link people to their profile page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply an extension of your existing code:

```
$game_name = preg_replace('/[?()#$^&%@\/|\[\]{}<>.,\\\]/', '_', $game_name);
```

But replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with blanks is still a safer bet, as different environments and different file systems within the same environment have different requirements on file/directory names.

Comment: this works very well, seems I had the code all along. only thing I can think of is what we would do for unicode charactors but I am guessing that the solution is to have an epic string with 10000 + charactors lol. thank you very much

Comment: also, if I had the reputation I would give you a up vote, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Almost good answer by Ariel.
He missed the colon ':' and quotation mark '"' which are illegal characters for windows dictories. Here's my updated version which makes strings safe for windows NTFS directories:

```
$game_name = preg_replace('/[?()#$:"^&%@\/|\[\]{}<>.,\\\]/', '_', $game_name);
```